# How to enable verification code

Tags: security-token

Hi for some security reasons,we want to enable verification code.How can i achieve this ,urgent requirement,need your help.we dont have strusted ip in our org,still it is not asking verification code whenever we are logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Restrict Where and When Users Can Log In to Salesforce**

There are various ways to do that

1. Login Hours
2. Two-Factor Authentication for User Interface Logins
3. Two-Factor Authentication for API Logins
4. Login IP Address Ranges
5. Org-wide Trusted IP Ranges

Please refer [help topic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_loginrestrict.htm&language=en_US&type=0) that outlines the various controls on login access to your org.

Comment: Two-Factor Authentication is not editable for me.

Comment: You require an `Administrative Permissions - "Manage Profiles and Permission Sets to be enabled"`

Comment: It is already enaBLED.

Comment: What profile you're using

Comment: system Admin Profiler

Comment: It works only for `Cloned Profiles` or `Permission Set`

Answer (score 1):

You can enable 2 factor authentication in order to achieve this requirement. You will need the salesforce authenticator app or google authenticator app installed on phone for users. Alternatively you can use authy app on pc/mac.

Link to instructions on how to turn it on-

https://www.turnon2fa.com/tutorials/how-to-turn-on-2fa-for-salesforce/